# How to sort IP address row in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Im using Kendo and Typescript on my app and i cant figure out how to sort row with strings representing ipv4 addresses

the sorting must look like this

```
1.1.1.1

10.1.1.1

50.1.1.1

100.1.1.1

100.2.1.1

255.255.255.255
```

inside gridColumns I have tried something like this:

```
        {
            field: "sourceIP",
            title: this.$filter('translate')('tcMetadata.modules.widgets.tcConnectionsGrid.gridHeaders.sourceIP'),
            type:"string",
            sortable: {
                compare: function(a,b){
                    var arr = [that.ipaddressregex(a.sourceIP), that.ipaddressregex(b.sourceIP)];
                    arr = arr.sort();
                    console.log(arr, "ARRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR");
                    return arr[0];
                }
            }
        }
```

Where that.ipaddressregex function is :

```
public ipaddressregex(ip) {
    ip = ip.split(".").map( function(i) {
        return ("00"+i).slice(-3);
    }).join(".");
    ip = ip.replace(/\./g, "");
    return ip;
}
```

The function simply adds zeroes the the empty fields and removes the dots
`12.10.1.1`   is converted to    `012010001001`

and then the javascript `sort()` method will take care

But i think my problem is in what i `return` in my case `return arr[0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compare function should return values like in the pseudocode below:

```
function compare(a, b, descending) {
      if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion) {
        return -1;
      }

      if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
        return 1;
      }

      // a must be equal to b
      return 0;
    }
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.sortable.compare

A JavaScript function which is used to compare the values. It has the same signature as the compare function accepted by Array.sort.

One notable exception is that we also supply a third parameter that indicates the sort direction (true for descending)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: y fixed it already, I  realised it must return 1 or 0 or -1 but thanks